# ipcRenderer.on is not receving (not working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

**This question is big because I tried to explain the best I could. Sorry for that. But I have this problem 3 times and I don't know why. I think I'm missing something essential but I coulnd't figure out.**
I have a React component that gets all accesslevels from database and list in the screen. My component send a ipcRenderer to the back-end and gets with ipcRenderer the accesslevels and list. My application can do this in the first time, but, when I add a new accesslevel and calls the function again, my ipcRenderer is sended, the back-end gets and returns the new list, but my ipcRenderer.once not working. I try to put console.log in ipcRenderer.once but doesn't print, and my back-end is sending right. This happened with two others components when I try to update the list again, I send a ipcRenderer but the ipcRenderer.once doesn't gets.

I will put some parts that I considered important beucase there is a lot, but if someone thinks that the error isn't here, I can update the question.

This is my component that contains the list:

```
 componentDidMount() {
  this.montarTela();
},

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.removerListeners();
},

montarTela() {
  ipcRenderer.send('get:accesslevels', {
    token: this.props.token,
  });
  ipcRenderer.once('get:accesslevels:200', (event, niveisDeAcesso) => {
    this.setState({
      niveisDeAcesso: niveisDeAcesso,
      listaDeNiveisDeAcesso: niveisDeAcesso.map((nivelDeAcesso, index) => (
        <PopUp
          contentStyle={{ width: '30%', borderRadius: '3%' }}
          modal
          key={index}
          trigger={
            <div className='estruturaDeUsuarios__botao'>
              <TextField
                defaultValue={nivelDeAcesso.label}
                InputProps={{
                  readOnly: true,
                }}
                fullWidth
                style={{ marginBottom: '15px' }}
              ></TextField>
            </div>
          }
        >
          <PermissoesNiveisDeAcessoPopUp
            montarTela={this.montarTela.bind(this)}
            nivelDeAcesso={nivelDeAcesso}
          />
        </PopUp>
      )),
    });
    this.removerListeners();
  });

  ipcRenderer.once('get:accesslevels:500', (event, data) => {
    this.setState({
      erroDeExecucao: {
        erro: true,
        descricao: 'Não foi possível listar os niveis de acesso.',
      },
    });
    console.log(`EstruturaDeUsuarios.jsx | get:accesslevels:500 | Payload: 
              token: ${this.props.token} | ${data.msg || data.error}`);
    this.removerListeners();
  });
},

removerListeners() {
  ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('get:accesslevels:200');
  ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('get:accesslevels:500');
},
```

And in that component, I have a button that calls a screen to add a new accesslevel. After add a new accesslevel (it's going to the database normally), it calls montarTela() (passed by props) to update the screen.

```
criarNivelDeAcesso(event) {
  if (this.state.label == '') {
    this.setState({
      inputLabel: {
        error: true,
        helperText: 'Digite um nome para o novo nível de acesso',
      },
    });
    return;
  }

  ipcRenderer.send('post:accesslevels', {
    label: this.state.label,
    token: this.props.token,
  });

  ipcRenderer.once('post:accesslevels:200', (event, data) => {
    //Recuperando o id para inserir na tabela AccessLevelHasMenu
    ipcRenderer.send('get:accesslevels', {
      token: this.props.token,
      where: { label: this.state.label },
    });

    ipcRenderer.once('get:accesslevels:200', (event, acessLevel) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.listaMenus.length; i++) {
        //Caso não seja true, o nivel de acesso não poderá acessar este cargo
        if (!this.state.listaCheckedMenu[this.state.listaMenus[i].idMenu])
          continue;
        ipcRenderer.send('post:accesshasmenus', {
          idAccessLevel: acessLevel[0].idAccessLevel,
          idMenu: this.state.listaMenus[i].idMenu,
          token: this.props.token,
        });
      }

      //Atualizando a lista
      this.props.handleCriarNovoAcesso();
      this.props.montarTela(); //**AFTER SUCESS, I CALL MONTARTELA()**

      this.removerListeners();
    });
  });
},
```

(I delete some lines of codes corresponding to validations, but I think it's not important beucase the ipcRenderer doesn't get in it)
As a said, it calls montarTela(), montarTela() execute ipcRenderer.send, it is sended to the bakc-end, the back-end returns but my ipcRenderer.once doesn't get.

Thanks and sorry!